# Magento 2 Order Shipment Email File

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping, shipment

I want to know, which file responsible for sending an email to customer when a shipment is created by admin (IF CHECKED `Email Copy of Shipment`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this file..

> vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php

```
if (!empty($data['send_email'])) {
    $this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
}
```

If `Email Copy of Shipment` checkbox is selected in Backend and you will try to `Submit shipment` then this code will send email to customer.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/ShipmentSender.php

And in above model file there is `send()` function available, that will send email to customer.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I also want to change the email address of recipient. Can you please tell that?

Comment: It means you want to send shipment email to different email, not customer's email ? or something else ?

Comment: Yes Your Right.

Comment: You can check this file. **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php** this may be helpful to you. There is one line **$this->identityContainer->setCustomerEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());** that set customer's email in **prepareTemplate()** function. You can add conditions there based on your requirements.

Comment: That one is for order email not shipment.

Comment: I think same file Magento using for all Orders, Shipments, CreditMemo and Invoice to send email. You can check this function **checkAndSend()** and it's all Sender file which is available on this location **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/** use same function and in this function you can see this line there **$this->prepareTemplate($order);**. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Your right man. Everyone is using this file.